# Signed ssl certificate not working on EBS AWS for Java Spring webapp

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, elastic-beanstalk, springframework

I am looking for help getting HTTPS working on my AWS EBS wepapp.  I have loaded the cert into AWS however I still cannot connect to my site via HTTPS.

- My application uses Spring 4.1 and Spring security 3.2.
- All the non HTTPS content on my app works fine.
- MY AWS EBS environment uses 64bit Amazon Linux 2014.09 v1.0.0 running Tomcat 8 Java 8.
- I followed the lengthy process to get a signed certificate from StartSSL.
- I uploaded my signed cert, key and chain to AWS via IAM **successfully**.
- In my EBS environment on AWS I enabled HTTPS, set the port to 443 and selected my newly uploaded certificate.
- re-deployed with the new settings.

Now when I try to connect via https it times out 
 - nothing is evident in the logs...

I am very green on AWS so i could be overlooking something.  My intuition is pointing me towards something not configured correctly in the load balancer.?

The load balancer shows

```
Port Configuration
Port 80 (HTTP) forwarding to 80 (HTTP) Stickiness: Disabled(Edit)
port 443 (HTTPS, Certificate: mycert) forwarding to 80 (HTTP) Stickiness: Disabled(Edit)
```

There are several options for the cipher that are over my head too.
help!

Comment: Use openssl s_client or similar to connect, observe, and help isolate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed create a new security group with HTTPS enabled, then add that to my instance. I can provide more details if anyone is interested.

Comment: I'm interested. Please edit your answer to include the details. There's no harm in "officially" answering your own question :)